# Golang version upgrade : Vendored module should be required explicitly in go.mod

Tags: go, versionupgrade

I'm a beginnner to Golang and I have a Golang app running on v1.14. I upgraded the version of the app to 1.17 by doing the following

```
go mod edit -go=1.17
```

Upon doing this, and running `go build`I see an error prompt which says:

```
go: vendored module gopkg.in/ini.v1@v1.62.0 should be required explicitly in go.mod
go: vendored module gopkg.in/yaml.v2@v2.3.0 should be required explicitly in go.mod
go: vendored module gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20200605160147-a5ece683394c should be required explicitly in go.mod
```

So I noticed these modules present in `vendor/` directory and I have these dependencies in `vendor/modules.txt` as follows:

```
gopkg.in/ini.v1
gopkg.in/yaml.v2
gopkg.in/yaml.v3
```

I tried adding these dependencies in go.mod's require section as follows

```
module code/workers

go 1.17

require (
    ......
    gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.62.0
)
```

Now when I run "go build", I get an inconsistent vendoring error

```
go: inconsistent vendoring in .../workers:
        gopkg.in/ini.v1@v1.62.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
```

Am I handling this in the right way?

Comment: You don't need to add dependencies manually in go mod file. Run "go mod tidy" and "go mod vendor" to sync dependencies.

Comment: Exactly: `go mod tidy`. And Update to 1.19.3, 1.17 is no longer maintained. **But**: The Go directive in go.mod probably doesn't do what you think it does. Just writing 1.17 doesn't "upgrade" _anything_.

Comment: @Volker , so what is the correct way to update the golang version in the app?

Comment: Compile it with Go 1.19.3. You have to updated _your_ Go installation: The Go installation you use to compile the project.